# How to clear HTML data list current options?

Tags: javascript, html, html-datalist

I am writing an dynamic data list. However, when I tried to update the list, the previous didn't clear. Are there any solutions?

Here is my code

```
 function loadDataList(selectedSchoolName)
    {
        var options = '';
        //document.getElementById('schoolNameList').remove();
        for(var i = 0; i < selectedSchoolName.length; i++)
        {
            options += '<option value="'+ selectedSchoolName[i] +'" >';
        }
        document.getElementById('schoolNameList').innerHTML = options;
    }
```

Thank You

Comment: do you have plunker for this ?

Answer (score 11):

In this instance, you don't want to remove `schoolNameList` itself; you want to remove the *children* of that list (the list items). There are a few ways to do this, but this one should work:

`document.getElementById('schoolNameList').innerHTML = '';`

Answer (score 1):

I like this one. Seems the cleanest I could find, but it is jQuery not vanilla JS DOM.

```js
$('#schoolNameList').empty();
```

Answer (score 1):

Simpler way and in Vanilla JS to do is by using the **node.replaceWith()** method.

Removing all childs in a loop can be a costly DOM operation.

Example:

```
const node = document.getElementById("schoolNameList");
if(node.hasChildNodes) {
   const newNodeToReplace = node.cloneNode(false); //false: because we don't want to deep clone it
   node.replaceWith(newNodeToReplace);
}
```

Comment: I voted +1 but finally, when I change my input, it not the replaceWith (under ubuntu 22 with firefox 117) doesn't work !

Answer (score 0):

similar issue, I first test @Shrey Kumar solution.
At first tests, it seems to work (no more duplicate entries) but if I change my input to another, the `replaceWith` doesn't work.
I test it too under console with no more success.

So I **finally** use `myDataList.replaceChildren()` that remove datalist children just before create new options and append its and it works fine !

[replaceChildren doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/replaceChildren)